# how to update clipPath attributes in D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to change the dimensions of a `clipPath` in a svg element. I don't want to create a new clipPath, so I tried using d3 to update or create the `clipPath` if not exists.

```
var svgCanvas = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([d]);

svgCanvas.enter().append("svg");
svgCanvas.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

svgCanvas.selectAll('clipPath').data([1]);
svgCanvas.enter().append('clipPath')
    .attr("id", "clip-area")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Now I can reference the clipped area with #clip-area
```

The problem comes once I have already created the clipPath and I try to retrieve it with `svgCanvas.selectAll('clipPath')`. The selection is empty and a new `clipPath` is created instead of modify the existing one.

How can I update the `clipPath`?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue. It's something about `"clipPath"` the string, which doesn't work with DOM querying. Maybe because it's camel cased. Got around it by assigning it a class and selecting it via that class instead (eg `selectAll('.clip-path')`).

Comment: This is a webkit bug -- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438

Comment: Same bug also affects Blink (Chrome/Opera): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237435

Comment: @meetamit: I used the suggested workaround, it works fine. I will keep on eye in case the bug is fixed, thanks.